# add second view

Tags: objective-c, ios, view

It seems to be simple, but I didn't find any information about this on this site. I want to call a view, but I don't want to use addSubview method, I just want to call a new view above the current one. And remove it after some time.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want to add the view to the screen?

Comment: If you want a view to appear it will HAVE to be a subview of some view or the main view with subview of its own. You can't have views that aren't part of the window hierarchy

Comment: no it isn't now -_-. You could already answer that one instead of telling me about possible duplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need a **NavigationController**.

There you can push views with the following code:

```
ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] 
initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

If you want to switch back to the old ViewController just remove the view with the following code:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: The ViewController is an own class which is extending the UIViewController.